# PHP condition make object extends

Tags: php, oop

i have 2 objects with methods lets say their name are 'animal' and 'lion'

```
 class animal{
   public $var1;
   public function doStuff(){
     // do stuff
   }
 }

 class lion{
   public $var2;
   public function doStuff2(){
     // do stuff
   }
 }
```

i need 'lion' to extends 'animal' but with condition.

```
 $type = $_POST['type'];
 if($type == 'animal') $obj1 = new lion(); // need to extends to `animal`
 else $obj1 = new lion();
```

so I thought the bast way is to marge the objects,

but i can't find way doing that without losing my method.

is there any way to marge it right or do extend on instance?

or any possible solution?

### Edit

it's part of MVC that i am doing for learning..

```
 class model{
   // many diffrent model class extends to this class..
 }

 class SQL{
   // this is a class of SQL functions..
 }
```

i dont want the SQL class load to model class automatically

i want to create function in the controller for doing that..

and i am try to avoid from this outcome:

```
 $this->model->sql->someFunc();
```

Comment: I don't understand what You are trying to achieve but clearly You don't understand OOP.

Comment: Most likely you are just violating every OOP principle if you want to do what you want (which is really not clear why yu want to do it form your question).

Comment: What's the goal of this ?

Comment: if I was understand OOP right I did't need any help so clearly you're right...
it's not important what i'm trying to achieve,
in the example I made I tried to simplify my problem, so u can help me to understand?

Comment: It is important what You trying to achieve and more important is to explain it more clearly so we can understand it and give You some advices.

Comment: In this case, instead of applying this logic, why not animal extends lion then you will be more flexible with your condition.
But what you ask to do is not possible (with my knowledge)

Comment: And what method are You "loosing"? Both classes have different methods and variables so if lion would extend animal it would have all methods.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you tell us maybe we can provide a better method of doing whatever it is that you are doing.

Comment: no i was tolkin about margin 2 object,
(with array_margin() this is the only solution i found)

Comment: i'll edit me question 1min..

Comment: In which case, a lion is not an animal..?

Comment: That's not the issue, I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not doing something along these lines:

```
<?php

class Animal
{
    public $var1;

    public function doStuff ()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}

class Lion
{
    public $var2;

    public function doStuff2 ()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}

class LionExtended extends Animal
{
    private $lion;

    public function __construct ()
    {
        $this->lion = new Lion;
    }

    public function __call ($method, $args)
    {
        $this->lion->$method($args[0]);
    }
}

if ($type == 'animal')
    $obj1 = new LionExtended();
else
    $obj1 = new Lion();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can make 2 different classes,

one classe LionAnimal that extends Animal 
and another class Lion that doesn't extend Animal

in this case you would have duplicate code in you LionAnimal and Lion class,
but because PHP only allows Single inheritance is no other way (you can only extend one class)

In programming languages you could have a lion and animal superclass and have a lionanimal (extends animal and lion) and lionnoanimal (extends lion)